# Unity + C# - "Resolution of the dependency failed"

Tags: c#, .net, unity-container, wcfserviceclient

***My application have a 10 WCFService ( WCFService Application on platform .NET Framework 3.5) with same software and hardware but only 1 takes this exception:***

When user is logged in invoke this method:

```
  public IService Select(SelectServiceRequest request)
        {
            IAxxxService anagServ = IoC.Container.Resolve<IAxxxService>(request.GetRegisteredService().ToString());
            return xxxServ;
        }
```

- with GetRegisteredService()  implementation with ClientIdentifier = 0 for first execution

  ```
  public RegisteredServices GetRegisteredService()
      {
          RegisteredServices res = RegisteredServices.Estxxx;
          if (ClientIdentifier == 0)
          {
              res = RegisteredServices.Anaxxx;
          }
          else if (ClientIdentifier == 1)
          {
              res = RegisteredServices.Prixxx;
          }
          else if (ClientIdentifier == 2)
          {
              res = RegisteredServices.Estrxxx;
          }


          else if (ClientIdentifier == 3)
          {
              res = RegisteredServices.LixxAnagrxx;
          }

          return res;
      }
  ```

  - with IOC code implementation and Initilization:

    ```
    internal class IoC{
      private static IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();
      private static bool isInitialized = false;

    public static IUnityContainer Container
    {
        get
        {
            if (!isInitialized)
            {
                lock (container)
                {
                    if (!isInitialized)


                        container.RegisterType<IService, EstxxService>(RegisteredServices.Esxxxxx.ToString());
                        container.RegisterType<IService, StaxxxService>(RegisteredServices.Anaxxxx.ToString());
                        container.RegisterType<IService, PrixxxService>(RegisteredServices.Prixxxx.ToString()); 
                        container.RegisterType<IService, LixxxAxxxService>(RegisteredServices.LixxxAnagxx.ToString()); 
                                    isInitialized = true;

                    }
                }
            }
            return container;
        }

    }
    ```

    }

i have this exception on execution method "Resolve":

> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been
>   thrown by the target of an invocation. 
>       ---> Microsoft.Practices.Unity.ResolutionFailedException: Resolution of the dependency failed, type = 
>        "ApCon.IService", name = "Anagxxx". Exception message is: 
>       The current build operation (build key Build Key[ApCon.StandardService, Anaxxxx]) failed:
>       The current build operation (build key Build Key[ApCon.StandardService, Anaxxxx]) failed:Index was outside the
>   bounds of the array. 
>       (Strategy type DynamicMethodConstructorStrategy, index 0) (Strategy type BuildPlanStrategy, index 3)
>       ---> Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.BuildFailedException: 
>       The current build operation   (build key Build Key[ApCon.StandardService, Anagrafe]) failed: 
>       The current build operation (build key Build Key[ApCon.StandardService, Anagrafe])   failed: Index was outside the
>   bounds of the array. 
>       (Strategy type DynamicMethodConstructorStrategy, index 0)   (Strategy type BuildPlanStrategy, index 3)
>       ---> Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.BuildFailedException: The current build operation 
>       (build key Build Key[ApCon.StandardService, Anagxxx]) failed: 
>       Index was outside the bounds of the array.  (Strategy type DynamicMethodConstructorStrategy, index 0) 
>       ---> System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.     at 
>        System.Collections.Generic.List1.Add(T item)     at 
>        Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.DependencyResolverTrackerPolicy.AddResolverKey(Object
>   key)     at 
>        Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.ConstructorSelectorPolicyBase`1.CreateSelectedConstructor(IBuilderContext
>   context, ConstructorInfo ctor)     at 
>        Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.ConstructorSelectorPolicyBase1.SelectConstructor(IBuilderContext
>   context)     at 
>        Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.DynamicMethodConstructorStrategy.PreBuildUp(IBuilderContext
>   context)     at 
>        Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.StrategyChain.ExecuteBuildUp(IBuilderContext
>   context)     --- End of inner exception stack trace ---     at

Could it be the lock instruction? It seems that types weren't registered and isInitialized becomed true

Comment: Do you append any buildoperations in your WCF-service? How do you initialize Unity in your service?

Comment: I have updated question, therefore Unity initialization is into IoC class.

Comment: Are you locking because you access it with a lot of threads?

Comment: Yes, it's a web application with back-end business logic in wcfservice multithread

Comment: Does Anagrafe have a parameterless constructor, or a ctor that can be resolved with Unity?

Comment: Anagrafe have a constructor with parameters, the code is in production environment from seven year, only few days ago has generated this exception.

Answer (score 0):

Near as I can tell, you're registering named instances of `IAnagrafeService`, but trying to resolve a named instance of `IService`.

My guess would be that the first derives from the second, so something like this should work:

```
string name = request.GetRegisteredService().ToString();
IService anagServ = IoC.Container.Resolve<IAnagrafeService>(name);
```

(Or you could change the Unity registration, of course.)

Comment: Sorry, i have changed the code because of client privacy. But i did a mistake: 
 i mean
     ' container.RegisterType<IService, EstattoriService>(RegisteredServices.Estrattori.ToString()); '

PS. I would substitute IAnagrafeService with IService everywhere

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's related to the services not being registered. That usually throws this Exception:

> The current type, IFoo, is an interface and cannot be constructed. Are
>   you missing a type mapping?

It can be a result of the lock. You can try this pattern instead:

```
public static class IocContainer
{
    private static readonly Lazy<IUnityContainer> Container = new Lazy<IUnityContainer>(() =>
    {
        var container = new UnityContainer();

        // Do your registrations.
        container.RegisterType<IService, EstattoriService>(RegisteredServices.Estrattori.ToString());
        container.RegisterType<IService, StandardService>(RegisteredServices.Anagrafica.ToString());
        container.RegisterType<IService, PrivacyService>(RegisteredServices.Privacy.ToString()); 
        container.RegisterType<IService, ListAnagService>(RegisteredServices.ListaAnagrafica.ToString()); 

        return container;
    });

    public static IUnityContainer Instance
    {
        get { return Container.Value; }
    }
}
```

If that's not an option, you can try to not lock the container itself:

```
internal class IoC{
  private static IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();
  private static bool isInitialized = false;
  private static readonly object padlock = new object(); // lock object.

public static IUnityContainer Container
{
    get
    {
        if (!isInitialized)
        {
            lock (padlock) // Lock on padlock instead.
            {
                if (!isInitialized)


                    container.RegisterType<IService, EstattoriService>(RegisteredServices.Estrattori.ToString());
                    container.RegisterType<IService, StandardService>(RegisteredServices.Anagrafica.ToString());
                    container.RegisterType<IService, PrivacyService>(RegisteredServices.Privacy.ToString()); 
                    container.RegisterType<IService, ListAnagService>(RegisteredServices.ListaAnagrafica.ToString()); 
                                isInitialized = true;

                }
            }
        }
        return container;
    }
}
```

I find this a good source for the singleton pattern.

http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx

Comment: Thanks for your support, maybe a some kind of concurrent access in container created the problem on the index of the internal list ( exception says: Index was outside the bounds of the array ).

Comment: So you where able to solve to problem? How did you do it?

Comment: I like the second solution. But i have a problem: i don't know how to recreate the error because i don't know what caused it. Do you have any idea how i can recreate this exception? I can also use debugging mode or force the code.

Comment: Sorry, no. I've never seen this particular error before.